# How to cast an interface to its sub interface?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

imagine you have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IInterfaceA : IInterfaceX
{
    //
    // declarations
    //
}

public interface IInterfaceB : IInterfaceX
{
    //
    // declarations
    //
}

public interface IInterfaceC : IInterfaceX
{
    //
    // declarations
    //
}
```

Now I want to replace the following three methods which perform almost the same with a single function:

```
class SomeClass
{
    IInterfaceA myVarA;
    IInterfaceB myVarB;
    IInterfaceC myVarC;

    void SomeMethodA(IInterfaceX someVarX)
    {
        myVarA = (IInterfaceA)someVarX;
    }

    void SomeMethodB(IInterfaceX someVarX)
    {
        myVarB = (IInterfaceB)someVarX;
    }

    void SomeMethodC(IInterfaceX someVarX)
    {
        myVarC = (IInterfaceC)someVarX;
    }
}
```

I thought about something like:

```
void SomeMethod(IInterfaceX targetVar, IInterfaceX someVarX)
{
    //
    // here's my problem
    //
    targetVar = (CastIDontKnowHowToPerform)someVarX;
}
```

which is used sth. like

```
SomeMethod(myVarA, someVarX);        
SomeMethod(myVarB, someVarX);        
SomeMethod(myVarC, someVarX);
```

So my questions are:

- Is it possible what I want to get?
- How to perform this cast I don't know how to perform?
- Perhaps a design pattern is more appropriate

I'm just looking for the best way to refactor those three functions by replacing them by a single one.

Things I've tried so far:
I used things like object.GetType() and object.GetType().GetInterfaces() which works well to **get** the type of an object or its interface(s) but none to **set** the type of an object to its interface.

Hope you can help me...

Regards,

Inno

**[EDIT]**
Ah, damn it... after clicking "Ask your question" and having a short look at it this seems to a be typical case for a generic function (or a template in C++-term).
**[/EDIT]**

Comment: C++ templates allow more than C# generics, they aren't equivalent.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent but in C++ you would use a template for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void SomeMethod<T>(out T targetVar, IInterfaceX someVarX) where T: IInterfaceX
{
       targetVar = (T) someVarX;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the best way to do it.

Comment: Do you need the 'out' keyword ?

Comment: Yes, you need "out", since we are changing the value of targetVal, rather than merely modifying what targetVal references.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is the "`is`" operator:

```
void SomeMethod(IInterfaceX someVarX)
{
    if (someVarX is IInterfaceA)
        SomeMethodA((IInterfaceA)someVarX);
    else if (...
}
```

A better method would be to put the operation into the IInterfaceX to avoid casting altogether:

```
void SomeMethod(IInterfaceX someVarX)
{
    someVarX.SomeMethod();
}
```